# Remember that ordinal parameters are 1-based

Tags: hibernate, hql

```
     StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
            List params = new ArrayList();    

    sb.append(" substr(jo.jobNumber, INSTR(jo.jobNumber, '-')+1 ) " +
                                "between (lower(str(substr('?', INSTR('?', '-')+1)))) " +
                                "and (lower(str(substr('?', INSTR('?', '-')+1))))");
                        params.add(fromjobNumber);
        params.add(fromjobNumber);
                    params.add(tojobNumber);
                    params.add(tojobNumber);
whereClause=sb.toString();
selectSql=" select distinct count(jo.jobNumber) from JobOrder jo where "
results = getDao().find(selectSql +whereClause, params.toArray());
```

I am getting the error:Remember that ordinal parameters are 1-based

Comment: sb is probably StringBuilder instance, OK, but what class is params instance of? Please provide more of the context code.

Comment: i have added can you pls check actually ab gets appended to the final query so when the above sb gets appended it gives the error

Comment: Also please provide code where you actually use both - sb and params. Like this, I don't see where the problem might be :).

Comment: i added the code which actually fetches the result

Comment: OK, but we still can't see how exactly is this used by Hibernate. Please paste code of find() method and all other related source (really, everything that enters in this process and might show us in what way is Hibernate actually used here).